# Print from column to one line with awk at windows command prompt

Tags: printing, awk, line, record, gawk

I try to print out the records of txt file which contains filenames(just 1 column only)

```
data1.txt
data2.txt
data3.txt
```

into one line

```
data1.txt data2.txt data3.txt
```

I have tried the following

```
awk -v RS='' -v OFS=',' '$1,$1' myfile.txt
awk '{print;next} {printf "%s ", $0}' myfile.txt
```

I have seen relevant posts but none of the advices work or I get as output

```
.data3.txt
```

instead of whole line with both 3 records

I use windows command prompt where I run awk
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$0}' file
data1.txt data2.txt data3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text file most likely has DOS-style line endings, so you have to account for the carriage return.

```
awk -v ORS=" " '{sub(/\r$/, ""); print} END {ORS="\n"; print ""}' myfile.txt
```

Do you *have* to use awk? This would be simpler with `tr`:

```
tr -d '\r' < myfile.txt | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: I guess you should change `print "\n"` to `print ""` or else you get an extra blank line.

Comment: Nope, I tested that. Since the ORS is " ", a plain `print ""` only outputs a space.

Comment: You care right, but I get one blank space on line before my prompt.

Comment: fixed it. Aside from the carriage returns, your solution is simpler.